# Mouse wheel not working in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mouse-wheel

A Logitech wireless mouse stopped working yesterday after a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.

I tried following the instructions for 18.04, substituting `20.04` for `18.04`:

`sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04`

but I get the following output:

`E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04`

Should I install `xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`, as I can see there's a release for focal [here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/focal/universe/base/xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04)?

**EDIT of 9 July 2020:**

The problem has resurfaced and installing the aforementioned packages won't fix it.

Comment: Running imwheel fixed my mouse wheel.

Answer (score 2):

go to settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> choose the Edge Scrolling:after doing that **Restart the computer**

[image]

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks it's been driving me crazy for aaaages.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the mouse USB connector and plugging it back worked for me.
(installing xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 didn't work, not removing the mouse battery)

Comment: I'm doing the same right now. Are you also dual booting?

Comment: No, just Ubuntu 20.04 on Thinkpad

Comment: Interesting - I've got a Lenovo as well (Ideapad Y700). I wonder whether it's a vendor-related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, installing `xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04` via Terminal fixed it.

Comment: The problem has resurfaced and doing this won't fix it.

Comment: Turning the mouse on and off when the computer boots fixes this issue. It's a bit annoying to do it every time but I haven't found a better solution yet.

Comment: i have done that with settings

Comment: Cheers, @KlienblatMoshe. I realised this happened after booting into Windows. Funnily enough, the most effective way of fixing it I found is to take the mouse battery off for a couple of seconds. I'll try your solution if this happens again.